# UISwipeGestureRecognizer applied to window

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

If I applied `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to a view, the swiped directions work as expected when the device rotated.  But if the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` was applied to the main window either in AppDelegate or from rootViewController (self.view.window, etc.) the directions only detected properly when the device is in portrait with bottom home button orientation.

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that the window does not support interface rotations. Only the `rootViewController` does that for you (or any `viewController` will do so). 
I suggest you to have a look at `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusbarorientation` to detect the correct device orientation. Once you have done so you can detect the specific swipe gesture yourself by comparing start- and endpoints of the swipe, depending on the rotation...

Besides that, is there any significant reason why you would want to do so? Why don't you add the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to let's say the `rootViewController`?

Comment: I need to let the UISwipeGestureRecognizer to pass through all subviews to the back... Now come to think of it, I do not need to use the main window, but just another view in the back.  Thanks for the question!